# New to programming how to make this code more concise

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Hi this is my first question so apologies if it is really basic - I am very new to programming!!!
Using c# in MVC I am trying to select object which has a Date property from entitymodel context. This date then selects the relevant Weight object and so on to get my list of "Set" objects.

The code works and does what I want but would like some general guidance on how to make this code more concise. Here is the code:

```
    public ActionResult showDiary(string datein)
    {
        LocalTestEntities1 dblists = new LocalTestEntities1();
        DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(datein);
        IEnumerable<ExerciseDiary> diary = from o in dblists.ExerciseDiaries where o.Date == date select o;
        var mydiary = diary.ToList();
        ExerciseDiary thediary = mydiary[0];
        IQueryable<Weight> weights = from o in dblists.Weights where o.DiaryID == thediary.ID select o;
        var selectedWeight = weights.ToList();
        Weight weight = selectedWeight[0];
        IEnumerable<Set> sets = from x in dblists.Sets where x.WeightId == weight.WeightID select x;

        return View(sets);

    }
```

It seems that I am taking too many steps here. I know that I am only returning one object to diary. Is there a way to get this object from dblists without sending to an IEnumerable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's always many ways to do things, but... I think the easiest way would be to use `First()` since you are always just grabbing the first result in a list.

Another way to make it a little cleaner is to put your LINQ statements on multiple lines like I did for `sets`.

You can also use `var`, which some people like and others don't to have the compiler infer the type.  I did this with `sets` below.  I feel it cleans up the code a bit when you have large declarations with `IEnumerable` and generics.

```
public ActionResult showDiary(string datein)
{
    LocalTestEntities1 dblists = new LocalTestEntities1();

    DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(datein);
    ExerciseDiary thediary  = dblists.ExerciseDiaries.First(o => o.Date == date);
    Weight weight = dblists.Weights.First(o.DiaryID == thediary.ID);
    var sets = from x in dblists.Sets
               where x.WeightId == weight.WeightID
               select x;

    return View(sets);
}
```

IMO this is easier to read than what you had in your answer above.

Comment: Closer, but no cigar. There's a couple of problems here. No parameter validation. Should be using DateTime.TryParse and handle if not valid. We are uncertain if there are foreign keys (weights->DiaryId, sets->WeightId). Should also wrap the object/dbcontext within a using statement. There's a deeper problem here because of assumptions. What if there are multiple diaries for a specific date? What if a diary only contains one weight? The latter case you could do a dblists.ExerciseDiaries.Where(d => d.Date == date).Select(d => d.Weight.Select(w => w.Sets)).FirstOrDefault()

Comment: I disagree, you have to make the same assumptions as the OP.

Comment: Thanks this works great and also showed me that I can use my class objects as well as var for these queries @Shelakel thanks for your input but I havent started to look at validation etc yet (this is next up) - there are all the foreign keys as you have typed. Only one diary per date and there could be multiple weights per diary

Answer (score 1):

Using the `First()` method will make things a little more concise:

```
public ActionResult showDiary(string datein)
{
    using (LocalTestEntities1 dblists = new LocalTestEntities1())
    {
        DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(datein);

        var thediary = (from o in dblists.ExerciseDiaries 
                        where o.Date == date 
                        select o).First();
        var weight = (from o in dblists.Weights 
                      where o.DiaryID == thediary.ID 
                      select o).First();

        var sets = (from x in dblists.Sets 
                    where x.WeightId == weight.WeightID 
                    select x).ToList();
    }

    return View(sets);
}
```

You should also wrap your LINQ to Entities data access in a `using` block so it's properly disposed of.

Comment: Tried this but the using block disposes of sets before I can return it to the view? Am I missing something?

Comment: You need to do a `ToList()` on the expression to actually run the query.  I've updated the code sample to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful using First() because it will throw an exception if there are no records.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public ActionResult showDiary(string datein)
        {
            using( var dblists = new LocalTestEntities1())
            {
            var date = Convert.ToDateTime(datein);
            var thediary = dblists.ExerciseDiaries.First(o => o.Date == date);

            var weight = dblists.Weights.First(o => o.DiaryID ==thediary.ID);
            var sets = dblists.Sets.Where(x => x.WeightId == weight.WeightID).AsEnumerable();

            return View(sets);
            }
        }
```

Warning: If it's possible the data wont always be there. Use `FirstOrDefault` instead and check for null values.